# SQL alternative to RethinkDB for real-time websites

Tags: sql, database, push, real-time, rethinkdb

I've been playing around with RethinkDB to create a real-time website and the changefeed feature is amazing. However, I'm accustomed to SQL syntax and Rethink's dynamic typing is turning me off.

Is there a free/open-source implementation of SQL that features a similar push-based solution to live updates?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "real-time website", but maybe: https://www.timescale.com/  or https://www.pipelinedb.com/

Comment: That's exactly it; PipelineDB looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton.